# How to join 2 tables with a common column but different number of rows?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have 2 tables (csv files).
The one table has users' names and twitter profile urls.
The other table has users' names and Linkedin profile urls.
They have different number of rows (not all users in table 1 are in table 2 and not all users in table 2 are in table 1)

Table 1

```
Name Twitter
user1 twitter_url1
user2 twitter_url2
```

Table 2

```
Name, LinkedIn
user1 linkedin_url1
user3 linkedin_url3
```

How can I join the tables by Name and create a table with all rows from both tables

```
Name, Twitter,     LinkedIn
user1 twitter_url1 linkedin_url1
user2 twitter_url2
user3              linkedin_url1
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out in **`Sheets`**:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(tocol({A2:A;D2:D},1)),
    map(Σ,lambda(Λ,{Λ,xlookup(Λ,A:A,B:B,),xlookup(Λ,D:D,E:E,)})))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to perform an outer join which includes all rows from both tables. To do this efficiently, you can use python and pandas to join the tables. The following code should work any 2 tables (`.csv` files):

```
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.read_csv('table1.csv')  # Replace 'table1.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
table2 = pd.read_csv('table2.csv')  # Replace 'table2.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
merged_table = table1.merge(table2, on='Name', how='outer')

print(merged_table)
```

After running the code, you'll have a pandas data frame called `merged_table` that contains the combined data from both tables based on the `"Name"` column. You can then manipulate, analyze, or save this data frame in certain file formats including `.csv`.

To replicate your specific example I created the tables you mentioned:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Table 1 DataFrame
data_table1 = {'Name': ['user1', 'user2'], 'Twitter': ['twitter_url1', 'twitter_url2']}
table1 = pd.DataFrame(data_table1)

# Create Table 2 DataFrame
data_table2 = {'Name': ['user1', 'user3'], 'LinkedIn': ['linkedin_url1', 'linkedin_url3']}
table2 = pd.DataFrame(data_table2)

# Perform join
merged_table = table1.merge(table2, on='Name', how='outer')

# Print the merged table
print(merged_table)
```

Output:

```
    Name       Twitter       LinkedIn
0  user1  twitter_url1  linkedin_url1
1  user2  twitter_url2            NaN
2  user3           NaN  linkedin_url3
```

The columns are merged with all rows from both tables and missing values are represented with `NaN`.